# Аналитика таблиц

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Есть ли для c# готовое решение позволяющие производить аналитику таблиц(DataGridView, datatable), к примеру сколько повторяющихся записей в колонки или путем фильтрации отсевать не нужные записи таблицы, строить графики на основании результатов таблицы.....

Comment: Класс DataTable позволяет делать некоторые операции - фильтр, считать сумы среднее и т п, Например Compute https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: не то мало функций